# Boot issues and choppy PC

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, temperature

Yesterday, when turning on my PC, it got stuck on a black screen while booting. So I pressed the reset button to restart it and then it gave me some error telling me to insert system drive and restart.

On restarting again, I got an error saying that there was a disk error and windows strongly recommends to run Check Disk. I ran it and was finally able to boot into Windows. Just to make sure that nothing was wrong with my hard disk, I took a look at the temperature. The temp was 41°C which is 3°C above what it normally used to be.

Today, when I switched on my PC it got stuck at the Windows Loading screen, but the PC started after a couple of tries, after which it has been choppy the whole time. Icons don't load quickly, HD videos are very choppy, flash player crashed while on youtube, firefox was choppy the whole time. I ran a SMART Hard Disk test with Seagate Seatools and it gave my hard disk a pass. I scanned the whole system with Avast antivirus and nothing suspicious was found. CPU and RAM usage is normal, but the Hard Disk temperature is now 46°C. I can't figure out how to solve this.

Comment: run `sfc /scannow`

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the HDD that has nothing to do with its temperature.

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath System acan is running now. I will update with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Check SMART hard disk. If you can put that drive in other machine, please view smart data. use crystal disk or aida64 to view each parameter of your hardk disk.